# Add Update Manager to the System menu in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, menu, update-manager

In Unity, the Update Manager was included in the power cog menu along with log out, suspend, shut down etc. But in GNOME Shell, I do not find such an option. Is there any extension or tweak to make `Update Manager` appear in that menu?

Comment: You can search for the Update Manager in GNOME Shell's Activities view, so I'm assuming you want it added there as a matter of convenience.

Comment: Yes, it would be very useful for me to have it under system menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way to solve the problem is achieved by using the `alternative-status-menu` extension.

## Install extension

If you have not installed the `alternative-status-menu` extension, type the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

## Patching

```
gedit update-menu-extension.patch
```

Cut the following, and paste in the editor.

```
diff -urNP org/extension.js new/extension.js
--- org/extension.js    2011-11-10 00:12:19.912240830 +0900
+++ new/extension.js    2011-11-10 00:10:14.779233789 +0900
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@
 const Lang = imports.lang;
 const St = imports.gi.St;

+const Shell = imports.gi.Shell;
 const Main = imports.ui.main;
 const PopupMenu = imports.ui.popupMenu;
 const GnomeSession = imports.misc.gnomeSession;
@@ -10,6 +11,13 @@
 const Gettext = imports.gettext.domain('gnome-shell-extensions');
 const _ = Gettext.gettext;

+function updateManager(item) {
+        Main.overview.hide();
+        let app = Shell.AppSystem.get_default().lookup_setting('update-manager.desktop');
+        app.activate();
+}
+
+
 function updateSuspend(object, pspec, item) {
     item.actor.visible = object.get_can_suspend();
 }
@@ -57,6 +65,10 @@
     item.connect('activate', Lang.bind(this, this._onPreferencesActivate));
     this.menu.addMenuItem(item);

+    item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_("Update Manager"));
+    item.connect('activate', Lang.bind(this, updateManager));
+    this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
+
     item = new PopupMenu.PopupSeparatorMenuItem();
     this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
```

Add a blank line at the last line, and save.

```
cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/alternative-status-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org/extension.js

patch -p1 < update-menu-extension.patch

sudo cp extension.js /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/alternative-status-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org/.
```

Restart gnome-shell and turn on the `alternative-status-menu` extension by `gnome-tweak-tool`.

[image: Screenshot of added entry (note: in Japanese)]

The above screenshot is from the Japanese version. "アップデートマネージャー" = "Update Manager".
Don't worry, the menu item ("Update Manager") will be displayed in English.

**Note:** If you will upgrade `alternative-status-menu`, you can not use "Update Manager" menu in session menus because `alternative-status-menu` extension will be overwritten.

## Recovery

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

Comment: Awesome. This is working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that ribbon to the left of the screen? I know when I am trying to keep a program there, I need to open the program and then right click it in launcher and press *Keep in launcher*.

Comment: The poster is using GNOME Shell, so the equivalent to pinning it to the Unity launcher like you describe is to right-click the running Update Manager's icon in the dock and select "Add to Favorites". But I don't know if that would be the solution they're looking for here.

Comment: WarriorIng64 is right. I am using GNOME shell, and that trick doesn't work here.

Comment: Well, I tried :P